# Remove add another from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an inline model in Django admin which is having `OneToOneField` relation with the parent.

```
class Child(models.Model):
 parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent)
 received_on = models.DateField(null=True,)
```

In admin Inline I don't want to show "add another button" so I have done something like this:-

```
class CampaignInfluencerShippingTrackingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    fields = ['received_on']

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
         return False
```

But it is still showing add another button the problem is with relation with the parent as it is having `OneToOneField` if I try with `ForeignKey` with same code add another button is not showing but with `OneToOneField` it is always showing.

Can anyone suggest me how it is working and what I can do to remove add another button from the Inline child?

I am able to add the model inline in parent but my question is related how to remove "add another button" from inline model.

Comment: You need to override template/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html OR template/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html from django-admin for that you need to add **template** folder (exact copy of django-admin folder's template folder) in your folder and override inner template / html file which has that button code. No django document found for this change.

Answer (score 9):

just add `max_num=0` or what you want

```
class CampaignInfluencerShippingTrackingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    max_num=0
    fields = ['received_on']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the user to be able to add exactly one `Child` using the inline, right? This should work, then:

```
class CampaignInfluencerShippingTrackingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    can_delete = False
    fields = ['received_on']
```

The `extra = 0` is probably what's tripping you up. When you include that, no form is visible; only the inline's heading ("Childs"), table header ("Received on"), and the "Add another Child" link. Once you click the link, the link will disappear and the form will appear. So it is, in fact, limited to only one child, as you would expect.

Comment: I want to remove add option from unity admin the child can be added using the API only.